# How to set Base DN from FreeIPA to Crowd OpenLDAP directory?

Tags: ldap, openldap, freeipa, crowd

In the Crowd's directory adding item, it can add OpenLDAP and must set `Base DN` in it.
However, how to find or set `Base DN` on the FreeIPA server?

Crowd:

[image]

FreeIPA:

[image]

If don't set the right data corectlly, it will cause this error when add a new group by selecting the LDAP directory:

```
org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name '[HIDDEN]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the default ldap base of your idm in any joined host in /etc/ipa/default.com.

The users base will be then cn=users,cn=accounts,$SUFFIX and the groups base will be cn=groups,cn=accounts,$SUFFIX, where $SUFFIX is the base found in default.conf.

This info is [here howto:ldap](https://www.freeipa.org/page/HowTo/LDAP)